# How to enable HTTP/3 support in Linux?

Tags: linux, http, web

Are there some stable open-source libraries need to install?

Comment: As a client or as a web server?

Comment: Both ones are interesting.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I hope to build it from sources with compatible kernel usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is to early for this technology.**

> **HTTP/3**
>
> 12 November 2018/ Jan Reilink /
>
> Daniel Stenberg writes on daniel.haxx.se blog:
>
> HTTP/3 is the coming new HTTP version that uses QUIC for transport!
>   That’s an interesting development to follow, HTTP(S) over UDP and how
>   that’ll go with (small) office and home equipment hardware, IOT,
>   middleware…

Source:

https://www.saotn.org/http-3/

Some more on the topic:

[http3-explained/](https://daniel.haxx.se/http3-explained/)

https://http3-explained.haxx.se/en/

Discussion:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19085534

Comment: Please don't misuse code formatting for emphasis